# How To Structure Table In Django With Overlapping Items

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a webapp using Django, that's going to be used to keep track of people and job/gig vacancies. Types of people who we're trying to help are distinct, but people may be in more than one category.

To give a more concrete example, let's that I have actors, singers, dancers. I could set up three tables:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    number = models.TextField(max_length=15)
    sex = models.TextField(max_length=1)
    dramatic = models.BooleanField()
    comedic = models.BooleanField()
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimals_places=2)

class Singer(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    number = models.TextField(max_length=15)
    sex = models.TextField(max_length=1)
    style =  models.TextField(max_length=20)
    range = models.TextField(max_length=50)

class Dancer(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    number = models.TextField(max_length=15)
    sex = models.TextField(max_length=1)
    style =  models.TextField(max_length=20)
```

It would be very nice, for a long list of reasons, to be able to identify people uniquely. If I was doing this in sql I'd have a `People` table, where I stored information like name, dob, etc. Then have `Actors` table that contained `PersonId` as a foreign key, and all the actor specific attributes. Then I'd create a view that allowed me to see the joined data.

However, I also want users to just be able to enter the information for a singer in a single form. I.e. not have to create a person, and then once they've filled in the `person` form, fill in another form that adds that person as a singer.

So, after all that, my question is: Is there a way to set Django up so that I can have a single form that writes to multiple tables, and return information from multiple tables, like a view? And if I can't, what the best way to structure something like this?

Even pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. I'm not even sure what the right terms to google are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django models support three models of [inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance). It sounds like you're after [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

> The second type of model inheritance supported by Django is when each model in the hierarchy is a model all by itself. Each model corresponds to its own database table and can be queried and created individually. The inheritance relationship introduces links between the child model and each of its parents (via an automatically-created [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField)). For example:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Place(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
>     address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
>
> class Restaurant(Place):
>     serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
>     serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
> ```
>
> All of the fields of `Place` will also be available in `Restaurant`, although the data will reside in a different database table. So these are both possible:
>
> ```
> >>> Place.objects.filter(name="Bob's Cafe")
> >>> Restaurant.objects.filter(name="Bob's Cafe")
> ```

As usual, you can use [the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/) or a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/) to expose any of your models to users.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I couldn't be the first person to have this problem.